# Mongodb match on all but first array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongodb document that contains an array of bookings like this:

```
{ id: myId,
  bookings: [
    {station: "Nurse"},
    {station: "Doctor"},
    {station: "Pharmacist"}
  ]
}
```

I have a view for each station where they see all records that are booked next. So for the Nurse, this would be: `find({"bookings.0.station": "Nurse"})`, returning every record where the nurse is the first element in the bookings array.

What I would like to add is a second view where all subsequent bookings can be seen, ie. records where the nurse is the `n`th booking for `n > 0`.

Is there a trivial way to do this? Or am I better off retrieving all documents first and then filtering on the actual document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do both arguments. It's perfectly valid. So the query contains both the positive condition that looks at all elements and the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) condition on only the first element:

```js
db.bookings.find({ 
  "bookings.station": "Doctor", 
  "bookings.0.station": { "$ne": "Doctor" }
})
```

Returns, and:

```js
db.bookings.find({
 "bookings.station": "Nurse", 
 "bookings.0.station": { "$ne": "Nurse" }
})
```

Does not. Which is the intent of course.

Comment: So simple and elegant, how did I not figure that out myself. Thank you.